# Expressing Loop Iterations as a function of n

Tags: loops, discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble with a particular question as follows,

```
n is an exact power of 3
(n=3^k , where k is a positive integer)

while n > 1
begin
    print "hello"
    n := n/3
end
```

I need to find a function of n that will determine how many times 'hello' will be printed.

I am having trouble with it because of the `k` variable.  Is this suppose to be implied within the equation.  I realize some test data is `n=3 -> 1 ; n=9 -> 2 ; n=27 -> 3` , but it just isn't clicking on how to incorporate k into the solution, if at all.  Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

- yes this is schoolwork, practice problems, but I am not looking for someone to just give me an answer I want to understand how to arrive at it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if you have something to exponentiate, what is the *reverse*
 operation?

Comment: a root, in this case a cubed-root

Comment: ... and if you want to return the *exponent*?

Answer (score 0):

Logarithms are your friends. =)

Comment: Heh, don't provide the solution. :-)

Comment: ya I thought about those, but how do you take into account `n` with a log; would you take log base 3, but when you do that you're getting k not n

Comment: @Extinct23: Okay, then ask yourself the very basic question for any problem: What is given, and what do I want do determine?